# Properties of an Autonomous Vector Field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields

Consider the following linear autonomous vector field on the plane:

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  \dot{x_1}\\
  \dot{x_2}
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  0&1\\
  0&0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  x_1\\
  x_2
\end{array}
\right), (x_1(0),x_2(0))=(x_{10},x_{20}) $$

Describe the invariant sets and determine whether the origin is stable or unstable.

The answer states that $\dot{x_1}=x_2$ and $\dot{x_2}=0$ implies $x_1(t)=x_{20}t+x_{10}$ and $x_2(t)=x_{20}$. Every horizontal line is an invariant set and that $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$ is unstable.

Can someone explain to me how did they get the expression for $x_1(t)$, and I'm not sure how to deduce the invariant sets for this as well.

Comment: $\dot x_2=0$ implies $x_2$ is constant. Since $x_2(0)=x_{20}$, $x_2$ is the map $t\mapsto x_{20}$. Substituting this in $\dot x_1=x_2$ and integrating implies $x_1$ is the map $t\mapsto x_{20}t+C$ and $x_1(0)=x_{10}$ implies that $C=x_{10}$